# Select random entry from MySQL with where clause

Tags: mysql, random, where-clause

I have this solution now:

```
rs = lState.executeQuery("SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) 
        FROM bases 
        WHERE user_id = " + userId + " AND is_valid = 1");

rs.next();
count = rs.getInt(1);

rs = lState.executeQuery("SELECT id, server, server_port, server_ssl,
        server_starttls, server_auth, email, password, auth_wholemail 
         FROM bases LIMIT " + count + ", 1");
```

But it isn't work because `FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*))` isn't return id with `is_valid = 1`.
So how to fastly select random entry from MySQL whith where clause (where is_valid = 1)?

Answer (score 7):

Try using the ORDER BY clause. Try this:

```
  SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM bases WHERE user_id = " + userId + " AND is_valid = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

That would return one random row from the table.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you are trying do, but this may help you (based on your question):

```
SELECT * 
FROM bases 
WHERE is_valid=1 AND user_id = <user_id> 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1;
```